# delay before function and cancel function on hover out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to reach the following. I want to collapse my menu after I hovered over the menu for more then 3 seconds. But when I hover out of the menu before the 3 seconds it must not collapse.

```
$("#sidebar").hover(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("collapsed-by-user")) {
        setTimeout(sidebarCollapse, 3000);
    }
}, function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("collapsed-by-user")) {
        sidebarNotCollapse();
        preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This is what I got so far. Collapse after 3 seconds is working but if I hover out before 3 seconds it still collapsing.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: `preventDefault();` ==> `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: `if(!$(this).hasClass("collapsed-by-user")) {`

Comment: can you share a working demo...

Comment: you'll have to pass the `event` in the `function(event) {//TODO}` and then do `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember the timer handle and use it with `clearTimeout` if the hover ends, if it's within 3 seconds:

```
var handle = 0;
var when = 0;
$("#sidebar").hover(function() {
    // Start the timer if we don't have it running already and we have the class
    if(!handle && $(this).hasClass("collapsed-by-user")) {
        handle = setTimeout(function() {
            handle = 0;
            sidebarCollapse();
        }, 3000);
        when = Date.now(); // Remember when it started
    }
}, function() {
    // If we have a handle and it's been less than three seconds,
    // stop the timeout from running by clearing it
    if (handle && Date.now() - when < 3000) {
        clearTimeout(handle);
    }

    // Reset our handle var regardless (for next time)
    handle = 0;
});
```

Note that we're clearing the `handle` when the timer fires before callilng `sidebarCollapse`.

(I'm not sure why you're doing that class check, so I left it in.)

Or updated per [Jamiec's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151983/delay-before-function-and-cancel-function-on-hover-out/35152109?noredirect=1#comment58022630_35152109) below; he's right, we don't really need to do that `when` check:

```
var handle = 0;
$("#sidebar").hover(function() {
    // Start the timer if we don't have it running already and we have the class
    if(!handle && $(this).hasClass("collapsed-by-user")) {
        handle = setTimeout(function() {
            handle = 0;
            sidebarCollapse();
        }, 3000);
    }
}, function() {
    // clearTimeout is a no-op if the timer's already fired
    clearTimeout(handle);
    handle = 0;
});
```

Comment: Do you need to calculate the time separately? Would it not be totally sufficient to clear the timeout if it exists (remembering to set it back to null/undefined/zero on successful completion)

Comment: @Jamiec: Yeah, we don't really need that, do we? If the timer's already fired, clearing it is a no-op.